# Armv8a NEON inline asm code: How to convert 16x8bit vector to four 4x32bit (integer) vectors?

Tags: arm, neon, armv8

I need to load 8 bit array and then convert every element to 32-bit integer using armv8a neon inline asm code. I have done it with armv7 but no idea how to do it in v8a...

The code I used in v7 is

```
"pld        [%1, #128]                 \n"
"vld1.u8    {d0,d1}, [%1]!       \n" 
"vmovl.u8   q8, d0               \n"  
"vmovl.u8   q9, d1               \n" 
"vmovl.u16  q0, d16              \n" 
"vmovl.u16  q1, d17              \n" 
"vmovl.u16  q2, d18              \n" 
"vmovl.u16  q3, d19              \n"
```

How can I finish this by using armv8a neon code? Or how can I convert the code above to armv8a? PS: In my case, I only need inline asm but not intrinsics...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unsigned elements, `USHLL`, `USHLL2` with the shift number 0 will do the job.

```
ld1     {v0.16b}, [%1], #16

USHLL   v16.8h, v0.8b, #0
USHLL2  v17.8h, v0.16b, #0

USHLL   v0.4s, v16.4h, #0
USHLL2  v1.4s, v16.8h, #0
USHLL   v2.4s, v17.4h, #0
USHLL2  v3.4s, v17.8h, #0
```

For signed elements - guess guess - use `SSHLL` and `SSHLL2` instead.

Similarly, there is no direct equivalent to `MOVN` on `aarch64` as well.

--EDIT

There are `XTN/XTN2` instructions that wore exactly like `VMOVN` on the other hand.

Comment: Thank you! However, USHRN and USHRN2 cannot be found in the aarch64. It gave the error `Error: unknown mnemonic `ushrn' -- `ushrn v19.8b,v17.8h,#0'`.  So I tried another one `UQSHRN`, but shift number 0 is not allowed, which gave the error ``uqshrn v19.8b,v17.8h,#0'`...Could you help with this?

Comment: @KathyLee My bad, it shall be `SHRN/SHRN2` for both signed and unsigned values. (signness doesn't matter since the maximum shift value may not exceed half the element size). That damn `aarch64` mnemonics (excuses, excuses)

Comment: @KathyLee Now I see that `SHRN/SHRN` also don't allow `#0` as the sift value, and I don't remember how I have dealt with that right now..... Just a minute, I'll take a look at my old projects. `aarch64` mnemonics really suck.

Comment: Take your time. Thanks for helping out. :)

Comment: @KathyLee These are `XTN/XTN2` instructions for "extract narrow" Grrrrrr….. I hate `aarch64` mnemonics. I'll edit the answer correspondingly.

Comment: `xtn` is the one corresponding to `vmovn` yes, but the question has `vmovl`. `uxtl` (or `sxtl` for signed) corresponds to `vmovl`. The "ARMv8 Instruction Set Overview" document (available e.g. at https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf) has got a great table that maps between corresponding AArch32 and AArch64 NEON instructions.